# Spring Java Configurations and BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I am using Java Configurations in Spring.
The goal is to replace beanDefinion class on a stage of BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

I'v got a bean

```
@Bean
public User user() {
    CustomUser user = new CustomUser();
    user.setName("UserA");
    return user;
}
```

and a new Class "NewTypeOfCustomUser" and would like to replace the CustomUser by NewTypeOfCutsomUser.

Before I've seen an example of doing this when a guy was on XML configurations. It is done using

```
BeanDefinition.setBeanClassName
```

method. However, the class of beanDefinition in my case is null on the stage of BeanFactoryPostProcessor's work. It seems that Java Config works in a completely different way that XML-configs.

So my question: is it possible to do this procedure using Java configurations?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand what are your requirements, you want to change the type of instance of `CustomUser` with `NewTypeOfCustomUser`. With the XML configuration, as stated by you, this can be achieved using the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. With java config, what you are looking is to modify the actual code of the `user()` bean method and I don't think that it's feasible.

What you can do is to use a `BeanPostProcessor`, that operates directly on the beans instances and not on the declaration as the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, and modify the instance of the required bean. Following an example of what you can do:

```
public class CustomUserBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public CustomUserBeanPostProcessor () {
        System.out.println("CustomUserBeanPostProcessor constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessBeforeInitialization method invoked");
        System.out.println(bean.getClass() + "  " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("postProcessAfterInitialization method invoked");
        System.out.println(bean.getClass() + "  " + beanName);
        if (bean instanceof User) {
            bean = new NewTypeOfCustomUser((User) user);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This also requires that you add a constructor to the `NewTypeOfCustomUser` that accepts a `CustomUser` parameter and manage the data accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I could do it that way. But my aim is to learn, not to find another way of doing this. I want to implement custom @DeprecatedCustom(newImplementation=NewImplementation.class) annotation. What my Custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor has to do is check if the class of a beanDefinition is annotated by that annotation and if so replace the deprecated beanDefinition class